# PL SQL - How to iterate for each column in a select statement?

Tags: sql, arrays, oracle, oracle11g

I have declared a table array type would like to add a bunch of values to the array so that I can later perform a select distinct from the array.

My values to be added to the array are strings like this:

```
"1","2","3", .....
```

I want to add each string to the array maybe something like:

```
FOR i IN SELECT "1","2","3" LOOP
    myarray(i) := ????
```

then later I want to select distinct values from the array. Is there an easy way to do this?

If I was doing this in SQL server, I would simply create a temp table, insert my values into the table, then select distinct from that table, but I am not sure if this is the best way with oracle?

Comment: would this work    select distinct t.column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('1','2','3','4','5', '1'))t;

Comment: Sure does, can you add that as an answer? Also, where can I find more information on these `SYS` items like ODCINUMBERLIST and ODCIVARCHAR2LIST? (not to be lazy, I can also just google it, but was wondering if you had references? These seem very handy to know about.)

Comment: not sure where I originally found the odcivarchar2 stuff. but I use it a lot. I think I saw a lot of people using it on the Oracle sql forum and I stole it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

would this work select distinct t.column_value from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('1','2','3','4','5', '1'))t;